# Javascript Interval functions not working

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a clicker game for a game dev class I attend, and I can not figure out why my interval functions refuse to work.

What I am trying to achieve with this:

every 100 milliseconds a variable will increase by a number, multiplied by another variable, lets use 10, and `i` for example.

The code I tried:

```
var interval = setInterval( increment, 100);

function increment(){
  money += 10 * i;
  document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
  document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = i;
}
```

This is refusing to work, and I was wondering if it was a problem with defining the variable, or just with the syntax.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the error in the console? Hard for us to help you with the information provided.

Comment: Where are `i` and `money` defined?

Comment: Do you define elements with id's `money` and `i` in the HTML?

Comment: i and money are defined globally through var tags, and document.getelementbyid tags. The console error logged is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: money is defined in the html, i is not.

Comment: If `i` is not defined your code won't execute. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code:

```
var interval = setInterval( increment, 100);

function increment(){
  money += 10 * i;
  document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
  document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = i;
}
```

And your comment:

> i and money are defined globally through var tags, and
>   document.getelementbyid tags. The console error logged is: Uncaught
>   TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

You need to have two elements with `id` as `money` and `i` respectively to work.

If you will try to execute `document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;` and element with id money does not exist then will throw the error which you are seeing in console.

As a prevention, you can code your function as follows:

```
var interval = setInterval( increment, 100);

function increment(){
  money += 10 * i;
  const elM = document.getElementById("money")
  if(elM) elM.innerHTML = money;
  const elI = document.getElementById("i")
  if(elI) elI.innerHTML = i;
}
```

And other possible error that may cause because of `money` and `i` variables not define, other fellow community members have explained it.

```js
let interval = setInterval(increment, 100);
let money = 10;
let i = 1;

function increment() {
  money += 10 * i;
  const elM = document.getElementById("money")
  if(elM) elM.innerHTML = money;
  const elI = document.getElementById("i")
  if(elI) elI.innerHTML = i;
}
```

```html
<div id="money"></div>
<div id="i"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `i` (as well as `money`). You probably also want to increment `i` so you get different values at every interval.

```
var interval = setInterval(increment, 100);
var money = 0;
var i = 0;

function increment(){
    money += 10 * i
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
    document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = i;
    i++; // increment
}
```

A few other ways you could increment `i`:

```
i = i + 1;
i += 1;
++i;
```

Also keep in mind that `++i` and `i++` have some particular effects when used in expressions (though that’s out of scope for this question).

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your two variables "money" and "i" with a default value.
Currently you are trying to increment a variable undefined with an undefined value ..
Do like bellow :

```
var interval = setInterval( increment, 100);
var money = 0
var i = 10;
function increment(){
 money += 10 * i
 document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
 document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = i;
}
```

Comment: Edit: In this code, we re-render the same value "i" every 100ms, which is useless.. But keep in mind that you have to defined your variables to use it.